# How to create shadow for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to create a shadow for the cells inside a `UICollectionView`. I've subclassed the cells and inside the `layoutSubviews` I've added the following code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;


}
```

But the cells gets higher and this is the result:

[image]

If I remove the:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

The cells are shown correctly (with a distance of 10px between them) but the shadow is not visible. What am I doing wrong? Also, is it correct to add the shadow inside the `layoutSubviews` method?

Comment: do you need gap between cells? set shadowoffset and remove shadowpath.

Comment: @VasanthanPrem yes I need spacing between the cells, if I remove the code inside layoutSubviews I can correctly see the spacing, but using that code in order to add a shadow results in the cells having no space between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I forgot to add this line inside the layoutSubviews:

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Now the cells has both spacing and shadow

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the shadow to be created outside of the bounds;

```
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    func dropShadow() {   
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false   
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor            
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5   
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)   
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0    
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0  
}

//Direct Add Shadow to cell  

Cell.dropShadow()
```